# R.cond Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: ramda.js

```
  const getStats = response => R.reduce(
    R.cond([
      (accum, val) => isCompleted(val), someIrrelevantFn,
      (accum, val) => isOngoing(val), someOtherIrrelevantFn
    ]),
    { planned: R.path(['data', 'length'], response), ongoing: 0, completed: 0 },
    response.data
  )
```

When I call `getStats(response)` where `response.data` is an array (I have verified this), R.cond throws the following error:

```
(node:40290) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at /Users/ash/dev/project/node_modules/ramda/src/cond.js:42:20
    at _map (/Users/ash/dev/project/node_modules/ramda/src/internal/_map.js:6:19)
    at map (/Users/ash/dev/project/node_modules/ramda/src/map.js:64:14)
    at /Users/ash/dev/project/node_modules/ramda/src/internal/_dispatchable.js:41:15
    at f2 (/Users/ash/dev/project/node_modules/ramda/src/internal/_curry2.js:29:14)
    at Object.cond (/Users/ash/dev/project/node_modules/ramda/src/cond.js:41:30)
    at Object.f1 [as cond] (/Users/ash/dev/project/node_modules/ramda/src/internal/_curry1.js:18:17)
    at XWrap.console.log.R.reduce [as f] (/Users/ash/dev/project/functions/commands/statsinfo.js:37:25)
    at XWrap.@@transducer/step (/Users/ash/dev/project/node_modules/ramda/src/internal/_xwrap.js:12:17)
    at _arrayReduce (/Users/ash/dev/project/node_modules/ramda/src/internal/_reduce.js:11:34)
(node:40290) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

This happens before any of the predicates are called, but here is what isComplete and isOngoing look like anyway:

```
  const isCompleted = R.compose(
    R.pathEq(['value', 'name'], 'Done'),
    R.find(R.pathEq(['customFields', 'field', 'name'], 'State')),
    R.prop('fields')
  )

  const isOngoing = R.complement(isCompleted)
```

I am using node 10.16.0 if that's of any relevance, any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're calling [`cond`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#cond) incorrectly.  The input is an array of arrays, the inner ones looking like `[testFn, consequentFn]`.

I think this would fix it:

```js
const getStats = response => R.reduce(
  R.cond([
    [(accum, val) => isCompleted(val), someIrrelevantFn],
//  ^                                                  ^
    [(accum, val) => isOngoing(val), someOtherIrrelevantFn]
//  ^                                                     ^
  ]),
  { planned: R.path(['data', 'length'], response), ongoing: 0, completed: 0 },
  response.data
)
```

Comment: thanks, i had just figured this out too :'D
Well, I'm suprised there was nothing on google about this, so i hope this will help some other people realise sooner than I did